# Merge multiple fcm Notification in ionic 3

Tags: android, ionic-framework, notifications, ionic3

I have created an application in ionic. The application receives notification and is working well. However, when i send more notification to the application, it stacks up in the notification bar (Android).

I want to merge multiple notifications into one like whatsapp. Example

*2 messages received from App*

Here is my Code

**app.component.ts**

```
 this.platform.ready().then(() => {
        // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
        // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
        this.statusBar.styleDefault();
        this.splashScreen.hide();
        this.fcm.getToken()
            .then((token: string) => {

                console.log("The token to use is: ", token);
            })
            .catch(error => {

                console.error(error);
            });


        this.fcm.onTokenRefresh().subscribe(
            (token: string) => console.log("Nuevo token", token),
            error => console.error(error)
        );


        this.fcm.onNotification().subscribe(
            (data: NotificationData) => {
                if (data.wasTapped) {

                    console.log("Received in background", JSON.stringify(data))
                } else {

                    console.log("Received in foreground", JSON.stringify(data))
                }
            }, error => {
                console.error("Error in notification", error)
            }
        );

    });
```

**Sending notification from PostMan**

```
    {
   "to": "ej-t7zm9yHw:APA91bFzLdt0DO7tHMMoANUxDHADZ65dd0ZQaBQZxjKOap6npsZkuG22t-xQDE7adRyTsp8qDpxExzXnLXO4DB5vAr4RY7_jQSdITx8K2JmwqVnxLOLawua5KAwfQcMfi_d  xxxxxxxx",

   "notification": {
    "title": "testing stack notification ",
        "body":"is it working",
          "sound":"default",
  "icon":"icon",

        "android": {               
                        "data": {
                            "title": "testing stack notification",
                            "body": "is it working",
                            "style": "inbox",
                            "summaryText": "yes its %n% notifications",
                                "noteId": "123456"
                       }
                   }


       },

       "data":{
       "content":"Please Check Report"
       }

       }
```